How to hide solution/project/properties windows in Visual Studio 2022

those three windws in red are really annoying and I don't need to view those windows especially properties windows, so how can I hide those windows in setting?

These are no windows. It's called Navigation bar. You can simply disable it in the Options, Text Editor > All Languages > General, Navigation bar checkbox.

